# Validate WSDL schema

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have this wsdl specification I have to code against (in asp.net 3.5), but it cannot be imported by visual studio 2010. I've tried using liquid XML, soapUI, xmlspy and webservice tester, and all of them give one error or the other. They keep saying that this is right, but I am unable to import. I want to be able to find exactly what is wrong, and what doesn't comply with the schema. The online validate WSDL tools doesn't really tell me much, or the specifics. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this WSDL?

https://secure.avangate.com/api/merchant/?wsdl

The specific method I am trying to test is 'addLicense'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `typens:CSOAP_CardPayment`, not `xsd:CSOAP_CardPayment`.

There are several other errors (seen via XMLSpy).

Comment: Thanks @john - do you mean altova xmlspy? How do you specifically see the errors?

Comment: I just open the WSDL and it starts showing errors. There are several like that (wrong namespace), then there is the fact that the `login` operation is specified twice.